# Convert the [converters]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

This burnination request is similar to the request done for the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag.

Just like the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag, the [converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converters) tag has no real use. The tag is ambiguous: the tag wiki has been hijacked to make it .NET WPF specific, but the tag is used for all sorts of questions, including tool recommendations, which are clearly off-topic.

The standard questions:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, as discussed above.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Some are, but those could be retagged. Often this tag is misused for off-topic questions.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. It often just refers to the action taken, not the context of the question.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Definitely not. It is being used for SQL, XAML, and many other contexts.

I propose to burninate this tag, and optionally create more specific tags for the levels of field such tag might be useful.

Comment: The title actually suggests a retagging, LOL.

Comment: I agree with this, but couldn't you argue that a converter is an actual piece of code, but "convert" isn't... well.. anything?

Comment: @EJoshuaS sure, but it still fails the four tests (from my understanding.)